# Calculate the sum using references only

Tags: excel-formula

I have a price table of items with id, name and price:

```
ID Item Price
24 Nail        $0.04
25 Screw       $0.05
42 Screwdriver $1.00
...
```

and an order table containing item names, one order per column:

```
Screwdriver  Screw
Screw        Nail
```

Now I want to sum up the prices of the items in each column and put the result into the top row.

```
$1.05        $0.09
Screwdriver  Screw
Screw        Nail
```

I tried:

```
=SUMIF(PriceSheet.$B$2:$B$1000;A2:A50;PriceSheet.$C$2:$C$1000)
```

which throws the error `#VALUE`

I came to think that this does not work because `criteria` may only be a single value; is this assumption correct? Can I solve this with a formula (without hidden columns) at all, or will this require VBA? How would I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it in `SUMPRODUCT()` and make it an rrayformula it works, but not without it, i.e.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(PriceSheet.$B$2:$B$1000;A2:A50;PriceSheet.$C$2:$C$1000)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This looks really good for a single column; but it seems as if I can't just drag the formula to the right to sum each of the columns.

Comment: It works for me. What happens if you try to drag it?

Comment: It drags but A2:A50 does not change to B2:B50; and if I try to change it manually, it says: "Cannot change part of an array".

Comment: That's odd, for me it does. Are you positive you don't have any absolute reference to the column B?

Answer (score 1):

Can you rely on your `PriceList` being sorted by Item, as in your example data?

If so, you can use this, entered as an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(LOOKUP(A2:A50,PriceSheet!$B$2:$B$1000,PriceSheet!$C$2:$C$1000),0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input; I fear that your formula does not produce the correct result. I am not sure what you mean by "PriceList being sorted by Item". It is sorted by ID, which does not show up in the order list at all.

Comment: Ah, I have understood. Once I reordered the price list, the result is the same as the other one.